# Oracle Apex 5: Using PL/SQL to insert a value to a page item

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create an auto-incrementing Primary Key for a questionnaire created by a wizard. The problem is, that I need the Primary Key to be inserted into the page item P2_ID (which is a hidden item) during the pre-render stage, so that I can have an ARF process run on each section of the questionnaire to allow the employees to go back and change their answers.

I can't seem to use a trigger, as that implements on submit, and I'd like the PK to populate as the session begins.

Currently, I have a process running in the pre-render stage with this PL/SQL code:

```
begin
    select SEQ_UAT.nextval into :P2_ID from dual;
end;
```

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to get this very simple PL/SQL code to populate the P2_ID page item!

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the debug log tell you is happening to P2_ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answering.

I was able to figure it out somehow. Basically, I removed the ARP I had running and made it a PL/SQL function, this allowed me to create a pre-render PL/SQL process to create a PK using seq.nextval.

Not sure why, but it seemed that the ARP just wouldn't work with the seq.nextval!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why that isn't working, but you could just use `MAX(pk_id)+1`. If you use `seq.nextval` it will increment every time the user refreshes page etc.

Edit: couldn't you also just set :P2_id's source to sql query and populate from there?

Comment: I disagree with your ability to use MAX + 1 for your is, at least in a multi user environment. This is a bug and will eventually result in a duplicate key. Here's why. In Oracle writing does does not block other from reading the data from the same table. But DML from 1 session is not seen in another until after commit. So the follow happens: For simplification lets assume the max pk on your table is 100. Now User1 signs in and gets session1, and user2 signs in and gets session2.

Comment: (Continued) Now user1 runs your procedure, gets PK=101 and inserts a row. However, before the commit user2 runs the procedure. User2 will also get PK=101. It may take long time but it will eventually happen.